# Trigger UpdatePanel on mouse over (as tooltip)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I need to display additional information, like a tooltip, but it's a lot of info (about 500 - 600 characters) on the items in a `RadioButtonList`.

I now trigger the update on a `PanelUpdate` when the user selects an item in the `RadioButtonList`, using `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `AutoPostBack`. What I would like to do, is trigger this on `onMouseHover` (ie. the user holds the mouse a second or two over the item) rather than mouse click but I cannot find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` on the `updatePanel` to watch the value of a hidden field. Then in the javascript `onMouseHover` event, increment the hidden value. This would fire the `AsyncPostBackTrigger`, updating the `UpdatePanel`.